# Correct usage of java list object

Tags: java, list, object

I have written a program to compute all possible subsets of a given array.

```
class Solution {
    /**
     * @param S: A set of numbers.
     * @return: A list of lists. All valid subsets.
     */
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        // write your code here
        if(nums == null) return null;

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        helper(res, list, nums, 0);

        return res;
    }

    private void helper(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res, ArrayList<Integer> list, int [] nums, int start) {

        //res.add(list);
        res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
        //System.out.println(list);
        for(int i = start; i < nums.length; i++) {
            list.add(nums[i]);
            //System.out.println(list);
            helper(res, list, nums, i+1);
            list.remove(list.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

The program works fine. However, if I use

```
    res.add(list);
```

instead of

```
    res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
```

Then it will give the wrong result. For example, when I give this input

```
    int [] nums = new int[]{0};
```

The expected output is [[], [0]]. However, I am getting [[], []].

Questions:
1.Because i am trying to add the same list object to the res object. I assume the res ArrayList object is trying to check if list object is already in it. Is this correct?

2.Why am I getting [[], []]? Since the list object will be updated to [0] in the loop, why isn't it being added to the res object?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between putting `list` into `res` and then altering `list` ;  and putting a copy of `list` into `res` and then altering the original `list` ?

Comment: I think I get it. After i add list into res the second time, I did the list.remove(), so the second addition is also empty now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing the perils of *mutability*, and you have found a common solution: the *defensive copy*.

When you do `res.add(list)`, you are putting a *reference* to `list` into `res`. Then you continue working with the same list, and modifying it. Because you're working with the *same* object as you put into `res`, when you modify it (here, with `remove()`), then print it via `res`, you see the changes in both places.

When you do `res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list))`, the constructor creates a new `ArrayList` object, and copies all the elements from `list` into it. From now on `list` and the new object have no effect on one another. When you modify `list`, your new object does not change. You have made a *defensive copy*.

Defensive copying is a well established way of dealing with this problem. Another way, that many people consider better, is to avoid modifying objects once created. Do some reading on *immutable objects*.

---

Bonus tip: code looks neater and has other "good" properties if you use the shorter interface name, rather than the concrete type, wherever possible. So:

```
public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) ...

List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with the standard terminologies which I am lack of and the bonus tip. Could you also elaborate on the good properties in the bonus tip?